# Finding the limits while conversion from rectangular to polar coordinates (A very basic question)

Tags: limits, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

When converting rectangular coordinates into polar coordinates it is usually done by $$x=r\cos(\theta),~~~~~y=r\sin(\theta).$$ Where $(r,\theta)$ represent polar coordinates and $(x,y)$ represent rectangular coordinates. Now it is easy to see that $$r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2},~~~~\theta=\arctan(\frac{y}{x}).$$ Now if $-\infty \leq x\leq \infty$ and $-\infty \leq y\leq \infty$ then $0\leq r\leq\infty$. But how does $0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi$? I ask this question because $-\infty\leq(\frac{y}{x})\leq \infty$ and therefore $\theta$ should have limits $-\pi/2\leq \theta\leq \pi/2$ instead of $0\leq \theta\leq2\pi$. Which very basic point I am missing here? Please clarify with some explanation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that you should discuss all the cases: $y>0$ and $x>0$, $y>0$ and $x<0$, $y<0$ and $x>0$, $y<0$ and $x<0$.

Comment: @Gustave so for the first case $y>0,x>0$ we know that $0<(y/x)<\infty$ and correspondingly $0<\theta<\pi/2$. For the second case $y>0,x<0$ we have $-\infty<(y/x)<0$ and correspondingly $-\pi/2<\theta<0$. Similarly we have, for the third case, $-\infty<(y/x)<0$ and correspondingly $-\pi/2<\theta<0$. For the fourth case we have $0<(y/x)<\infty$ and therefore $0<\theta<\pi/2$. Overall we can see that $-\pi/2<\theta<\pi/2$. What do you say?

Comment: If $x>0$ and $y>0$ then $\theta=arct(y/x) $, if  If $x<0$ and $y>0$ then $\theta=\pi -arct(y/x)$ and so one.

Comment: @Gustave so this means my definition of $\theta$ in my post is wrong and it should be $\theta=\pi-\arctan(y/x)$. Right?

Comment: yeah, take an example, if $x=-1$ and $y=0$, you will find $\theta=0$

Comment: @Gustave but at the same time we have $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$ the incorrectness of $\theta$ expression would also mean that these definitions are also incorrect. Right?

Comment: @Gustave I can understand it geometrically but I just want to see why it can't be said without resorting to the geometric interpretation.

Comment: When $\theta$ varying in $(0,2\pi)$, $r=sin(\theta)$ and $y=rcos(\theta)$ across all $\mathbb{R^2}$

Comment: @Gustave I agree with you completely but you know this through the geometrical interpretation. But the equations for $x$ and $y$ describe $\theta=\arctan(y/x)$ and for which we have $-\pi/2<\theta<\pi/2$. THat is my problem. The equations do not comply with $0<\theta<2\pi$

Comment: $y/x=tan(\theta)$, observe that the function $tan$ is invertible on all the intervals of the forme  $(-\pi /2+k\pi,\pi /2+k\pi)$ for all integer $k$. Can you see what I want to tell you.

Comment: @Gustave I am extremely thankful to you for your comments but unfortunately I am unable to understand it in equation form

Comment: Even with equation $\tan(\theta)=(y/x)$ we will have to see the individual signs of $x,y$ to see in which quadrant $\theta$ lies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is created by your claim that

> Now it is easy to see that $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, $\theta=\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$.

The second one is definitely false. (If it's any consolation, this is a very popular misconception … which doesn't make it any more true, though.) And the first one may be true or false depending on an interpretation — some definitions of polar coordinates require $r\ge0$, while other definitions allow $r$ to be negative. Still, even if we stick with non-negative $r$, the second claim is wrong. And we start with a wrong premise, no wonder we end up confused and things don't work out and nothing makes sense.

The real definition of the polar angle $\theta$ is, roughly speaking, that it must point from the origin in the direction of the point $(x,y)$. So it naturally is very *geometrical*. From this definition, we can develop different formulas for $\theta$ depending on the location of the point $(x,y)$. In some cases — when $(x,y)$ lies in the first of the fourth quadrant (as well as on the $y$-axis or on the positive side of the $x$-axis) — we can take $\theta=\arctan(y/x)$. But in other cases this expression for $\theta$ can't possibly be true, simply because $\arctan$ returns values between $\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$, i.e. within quadrants I and IV only, but the actual point isn't there!

Moreover, for each point $(x,y)$ there are *infinitely many* corresponding values of $\theta$, due to the periodic nature of revolving around the origin. Say, for the cartesian point $(1,1)$, some possible values of the polar angle are $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{9\pi}{4},-\frac{7\pi}{4},\ldots$ and so on, and so forth. If we have any reasons for doing so, we can restrict $\theta$ to be within $0\le\theta<2\pi$, but we don't have to restrict it to that interval — generally, $\theta$ can be any real number.

So, to answer your question:

> Which very basic point I am missing here?

You took a false statement as a definition, which lead to all this trouble.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer. So my conclusion from your answer is that I should avoid an equation for $\theta$ for finding the limits of $\theta$ and find limits of $\theta$ geometrically. Thanks again.

Comment: @FrankMoses: You're very welcome! I'm glad I could help. :-)